# xamarin.mac / monomac switch betweeen views

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, monomac, xamarin.mac

I'm following [this tutorial](http://youtu.be/ScB9ZJbkCJI?t=18m2s) trying to change between different views on my application. Because the tutorial is written in Objective-C and not C# it's kinda hard for me to translate (I'm a newbie in C# and no Objective-C experience). This is my current code that doesn't work (error in line `ourViewController = constFirstView;`):

```
    public const int constFirstViewTag = 0;
    public const int constSecondViewTag = 1;

    public NSViewController ourViewController = new NSViewController();

    partial void changeView (NSObject sender)
    {
        var item = sender as NSToolbarItem;
        int tag = Convert.ToInt32(item.Tag);

        changeViewController(tag);
    }

    public void changeViewController(int tag)
    {
        switch (tag) {
        case constFirstViewTag:
            ourViewController = new GeneralController();
            break;
        case constSecondViewTag:
            ourViewController = new AccountController();
            break;
        }

        ourView.AddSubview (ourViewController.View);
    }
```

ourView is my customView control.
The code from the tutorial you can see [here](http://youtu.be/ScB9ZJbkCJI?t=16m40s).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got the solution. Here's the working switch-statement (I also updated the code above):

```
switch (tag) {
    case constFirstViewTag:
        ourViewController = new GeneralController();
        break;
    case constSecondViewTag:
        ourViewController = new AccountController();
        break;
}
```